# Can the derivative of an absolutely continuous real function have a simple discontinuity?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives, examples-counterexamples, lebesgue-measure

If $f'$ exists everywhere, then we know that it cannot have any simple discontinuities. But in this case we only know that $f'$ exists a.e. (since $f$ is absolutely continuous).

More specifically, I've also been assuming that $f'$ is increasing (on the set where it is defined). In this case, $f'(x+)$ exists everywhere, and I've been asking if there can be a point $x$ such that $f'(x)$ exists but $f'(x)<f'(x+)$. (We know this cannot happen if $f$ is differentiable on $[x, x+\epsilon)$.)

Answer (score 1):

No, $f'(x)$ can  not have simple discontinuities.

**Theorem**

Let $f(x)$ be differentiable on some interval $(a,b)$, and continuous on $[a,b]$.

If $\lim_{x \to a^+}f'(x)$ exists, then it is equal to $f'_+(a)$ (the right derivative), same for the left derivative. (I will prove this bellow)

---

Consequence:

Because a simple discontinuity at $c\in(a,b)$ implies existence of sideways limits $\lim_{x \to c^+}f'(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to c^-}f'(x)$, and because $f$ is differentiable at $c \ $ $\left(f'_+(c) = f'_-(c) = f'(c)\right)$, it follows from the theorem above that

$$\lim_{x \to c^+}f'(x) = f'_+(c) = f'(c)  = f'_-(c) = \lim_{x \to c^-}f'(x)$$

And thus $f'$ cannot have a simple discontinuity.

---

Proof of theorem stated above:
$$
f'_+(a) = \lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac{f(a + h) - f(a)}{h},
$$

Now if you apply the MVT on the interval $[a,a+h]$,

\begin{equation}
\frac{f(a + h) - f(a)}{h} = f'(a +h\theta)
\end{equation}

where $\theta \in (0,1)$

Because $\lim_{x \to a^+}f'(x) = L$ exists,

$$
\lim_{h \to 0^+}f'(a +h\theta) = L = \lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac{f(a + h) - f(a)}{h} = f'_+(a)
$$

Comment: The point of the question is that, although we are assuming that $f'$ exists at the point of simple discontinuity $x$, it may not exist in any intervals of the form $(c,x]$ or $[x,d)$, and hence the MVT cannot be applied as above.

Comment: The MVT is applied on $f$, and $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$, thus the MVT can be applied on every interval embedded in $(a,b)$.  You are mentioning a point of simple discontinuity, it cannot exist neither in $f$ because it's differentiable, and neither in $f'$ because of the above theorem.

Comment: We are not assuming that $f$ is differentiable in any interval. All we know is that $f'$ exists a.e. (and, of course, at the point of simple discontinuity).

Comment: If $f'$ doesn't exist any interval, then you are saying that it exists at a point, this is fine, but then $f'$ is trivially continuous at that point because it is an isolated point of it's domain.

Comment: No, the domain of $f'$ is actually dense in the reals (its complement has Lebesgue measure zero).

Comment: My mistake, you are right, the domain of a function can be dense in the reals (such as $\mathbb{Q}$) but that sort of function will have no limit anywhere, because the limit of a function at $a$ in $R$ is defined only at points where there exist neighborhoods of $\delta$ such that all points in that neighborhood (except the point $a$) (an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ without the $a$) are in the domain of $f$.

Comment: Let $D$ be the domain of $f'$. Assuming that $f'$ is also increasing (on $D$),  then define $f'(x+)=\inf_{y\in D,\ y>x}f'(y)$, which exists for every real $x$ (every real is a limit point of $D$). One question is whether there is an $x$ for which $f'(x)$ exists and $f'(x)<f'(x+)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17156/discussion-between-vladimirm-and-aubrey).

Answer (score -1):

I believe that $f(x) = |x|$ is a counterexample. Derivative exists except at $x = 0$, but is discontinuous there.

Comment: I'm looking for a point $x$ where $f'$ is defined but has a simple discontinuity.